# Middleware with except parameter as array. Where syntax is described in official documentation?

Tags: php, laravel

For example, if we need use `auth` middleware for some controller, except some methods, we can use:

```
public function __construct() {
    $this->middleware('auth', ['except'=>['method1','method2']]);
}
```

This works, but I read this one tutorial. where is this syntax described in official documentation? I'm looking [here](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/controllers), but not found, where this syntax is described.

Please explain, where this syntax comes from ?

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/controllers#controller-middleware

Comment: @Saly3301 - There is only 2 place, where `except`  is mentioned 1: `$this->middleware('subscribed')->except('store');` 2: `Route::resource('photos', 'PhotoController')->except([
    'create', 'store', 'update', 'destroy'
]);` but where is exact syntax like I wroted in question ?

Answer (score 1):

It's mentioned in the exact page you linked to, [here](https://laravel.com/docs/controllers#controller-middleware)

However, it is more convenient to specify middleware within your controller's constructor. Using the `middleware` method from your controller's constructor, you may easily assign middleware to the controller's action. You may even restrict the middleware to only certain methods on the controller class:

```php
class UserController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Instantiate a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('auth');

        $this->middleware('log')->only('index');
        // THIS IS WHAT YOU ARE LOOKING FOR
        $this->middleware('subscribed')->except('store');
    }
}
```

Truth be told, it's not **explicitly** mentioned but it's there

> Pro Tip: use CTRL+F to find a keyword you're looking for in a given page

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks, but how can use multiple methods with this syntax? I tried:  `$this->middleware('auth')->except('method1');
        $this->middleware('auth')->except('method2');` but this not works.

Comment: pass the methods as an array parameter